# Is doing_wp_cron a necessary query string when scheduling cron.php as a cron job?

Tags: wp-cron, server, query-string

I have seen various ways to schedule the WordPress cron so that it is triggered by the server. Some will run the php file directory from the crontab and others will use a wget and reference the url. I have noticed some [sites suggesting this](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-wp-cron/):

```
wget -q -O - https://domain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1
```

What is the difference between this and just using

```
wget -q -O - https://domain.com/wp-cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: It appears the `?doing_wp_cron` is related to the use of `WP_ALTERNATE_CRON` in `wp-config.php` -- see [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/doing_wp_cron-3/). If you're not using the alternate cron system to schedule WP jobs, you should be able to ignore the `?doing_wp_cron` querystring. (If I'm wrong, please let me know.)

Comment: Thank you, Pat. Honestly I have not come across WP_ALTERNATE_CRON so that is probably the missing piece in my knowledge. I will ignore it for now then.  Thank you and best!